# JSON data group by

Tags: javascript, json

I have json data which contain the whole database record now i need to perform group by on this return json data with sorting on particular category.

I think sorting is easy to do on json data but i am not sure how i can go with group by. I need to group by on particular set of data.

Any help/suggestion would be great help.

Thanks
ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = [{ "session":"1","page":"a"},
       { "session":"1","page":"b"},
       { "session":"1","page":"c"},
       { "session":"2","page":"d"},
       { "session":"2","page":"f"},
       { "session":"3","page":"a"}];

function GroupBy(myjson,attr){
    var sum ={};

    myjson.forEach( function(obj){
       if ( typeof sum[obj[attr]] == 'undefined') {
         sum[obj[attr]] = 1;
       }
       else {
         sum[obj[attr]]++;
       } 
    });
    return sum;
}

var result = GroupBy(obj,"page");

console.log("GroupBy:"+ JSON.stringify(result));
///  GroupBy(obj,"session")  --> GroupBy:{"1":3,"2":2,"3":1}
///  GroupBy(obj,"page")  --> GroupBy:{"a":2,"b":1,"c":1,"d":1,"f":1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the http://linqjs.codeplex.com or [http://jslinq.codeplex.com](http://jslinq.codeplex.com/). It's javascript libraries that mimics LINQ. Here is other questions like yours:[Javascript Dynamic Grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267158/javascript-dynamic-grouping)

Comment: Thanks for u r answer. LINQ never make any sense in mycase as we are working on inhouse lang. we developed our own framerwork that run the javascript engine. So i need to do this group by at javascript level without any third party framework(ie. .NET).

Comment: @ravi - linqjs is a pure javascript library that has nothing to do with .net. It just mimics its linq query functionality.

Comment: Thanks Elian. But i know its very different approach in our development..I am writing javascript for desktop application. Anyways do you know without LINQ.js how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj = [{Poz:'F1',Cap:10},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5},{Poz:'F2',Cap:20},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5},{Poz:'F1',Cap:15},{Poz:'F2',Cap:5},{Poz:'F3',Cap:5},{Poz:'F4',Cap:5},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5}];
Array.prototype.sumUnic = function(name, sumName){
    var returnArr = [];
    var obj = this;
    for(var x = 0; x<obj.length; x++){
        if((function(source){
            if(returnArr.length == 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                var isThere = [];
                for(var y = 0; y<returnArr.length; y++){
                    if(returnArr[y][name] == source[name]){
                        returnArr[y][sumName] = parseInt(returnArr[y][sumName]) + parseInt(source[sumName]);
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        isThere.push(source);
                    }
                }
                if(isThere.length>0)returnArr.push(source);
                return false;
            }
        })(obj[x])){
            returnArr.push(obj[x]);
        }
    }
    return returnArr;
}
obj.sumUnic('Poz','Cap');
// return "[{"Poz":"F1","Cap":45},{"Poz":"F2","Cap":25},{"Poz":"F3","Cap":5},{"Poz":"F4","Cap":5}]"
```